# C++ standard library symbols bound at runtime to other libraries

Tags: g++, runtime, visibility, loader, libstdc++

I have a C++ application built with GCC 8.3 on RHEL 6 and linking with a bunch of internal and external shared libraries.

I am trying to understand how the loader binds my application symbols at runtime.

What I have observed and I cannot understand is why some symbols from the **libstdc++.so** get mapped to my application and shared libraries:

```
LD_DEBUG=bindings ldd -r main
[...]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./libshared01.so [0]: normal symbol `std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy::_M_next_bkt(unsigned long) const' [GLIBCXX_3.4.18]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./libshared02.so [0]: normal symbol `std::_Hash_bytes(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)' [CXXABI_1.3.5]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./libshared03.so [0]: normal symbol `char* std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_construct<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)' [GLIBCXX_3.4.14]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./libshared03.so [0]: normal symbol `char* std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag)' [GLIBCXX_3.4.14]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./libshared04.so [0]: normal symbol `std::__future_base::_Async_state_common::~_Async_state_common()' [GLIBCXX_3.4.17]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to ./main [0]: normal symbol `std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
```

Not all standard symbols are bound outside of the **libstdc++.so** but only a few, all the others are mapped as I would expect:

```
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `std::terminate()' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)' [GLIBCXX_3.4.9]
binding file /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::sentry::~sentry()' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
```

I am not using any visibility flags from GCC or visibility attributes in my code.

However I was assuming that all these symbols clearly identified as standard ones would be mapped to the **libstdc++.so** by default.

My underlying issue is that my application behavior/performances seems to be therefore randomly dependent on a symbol mapping process that I don't control. If one of my external dependency is highly optimized and all the standard string symbols of my application get suddenly picked from this external library it feels like a problem.

Can someone shed some light on this behavior? Is it expected and documented?

Answer (score 0):

> However I was assuming that all these symbols clearly identified as standard ones would be mapped to the libstdc++.so by default.

Why?  Many of the symbols that you are looking at are templates, and are instantiated by the compiler when you build. They may not exist in libstdc++. [ Some specializations, like (say) `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`] maybe be instantiated in the dylib to save space in your app; but certainly not all of them.

You can get a list of symbols exported from libstdc++.so using `nm -g` (if I remember correctly). Some versions of `nm` have a `-demangle` flag as well. You will probably be surprised by the contents of that list.

Comment: I did the test indeed: `nm -gDC --defined-only /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`
It makes sense that templates instantiated during the build would be stored in the shared library.

Comment: However, I would have expected these symbols to be "private" and not being visible from the application or the other libraries.
When investigating a performance gain, I noticed that some templated string symbols of my application/libraries were relocated to another newly optimized library.
So even without actually using the new library, the performance gain was there.
It may be a build issue then.